# How to Download a PDF File from Online SharePoint using python?

Tags: python, pdf, sharepoint

**How to Download a PDF File from Online SharePoint using python?**

**I've tried this code: but whenever I try this it downloads a broken file**

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File

url = "SharePointFilePath"
username= "Username"
password= "Password"

ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password)   
ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
response = File.open_binary(ctx, "SharepointURL")
with open("file.pdf","wb") as local_file:
    local_file.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write, not to read:

```
with open("file.pdf","wb") as local_file:
    local_file.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use another flag **'wb'** instead of **'rb'** and ****write** method** instead of **read**

```
with open('file.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

[Read about flags](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)